# That was mandatory as of or is mandatory as of

Tags: word-choice

The sentence for reference:

> Learn about commercial wireless lighting controls that will help
>   satisfy the new NEBC2017 that was mandatory as of January 1, 2019.

In this sentence, the usage of *was* seems correct since the date the new lighting standard - being the NEBC2017 - had been enacted was in the past. However, I can't shrug the feeling that using *is* makes more sense since the standard is still in place today.

Are both usages correct? If so, what are their different connotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just writing, and technical regulatory writing at that, so nothing about this would have the gravitas of literature grammar.

The [**mood**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense%E2%80%93aspect%E2%80%93mood) of the sentence is **[imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood)** ("*Learn about...*") up until that dependent relative clause "*that was mandatory*." As you point out, this is further complicated by the semantic implications of "mandatory," i.e., it might as well be conjugated in the present [**tense**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense%E2%80%93aspect%E2%80%93mood) if it is still applicable, and referred to with a simple [**copula**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copula). As a matter of historical record, though, "was mandatory" seems like a broken construction (e.g., "mandatorized") in the [**passive**](https://www.bing.com/search?q=passive%20voice&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR) [**voice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) of a latin *mandare* or "to mandate,", e.g., "*It was mandated January 2011.*"

As it reads now, it reads that, if you were to check the "status" of NEBC2017 in December 2018, it was not mandatory, but in January 2019, it was mandatory.

Me personally I would write something like:

> Learn about commercial wireless lighting controls that help satisfy [the new] NEBC2017 (mandated January 1, 2019).